# How to use swap to get result in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to write the function collect which can combine the sublists into a list, like:

```
user=> (collect '(a b c d e) 1)
((a)(b)(c)(d)(e))
user=> (collect '(a b c d e) 2)
((a b)(c d)(e))
user=> (collect '(a b c d e) 5)
(a b c d e))
```

this is my code:

```
(defn collect [lst num]
  (loop [l lst res (atom ())]
    (if (<= (count l) num) @res
        (recur (drop num l) (swap! res conj (take num (drop num l)))))))
```

But when I run

```
user=> (collect '(a b c d e) 1)
```

I got the error:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IAtom  clojure.core/swap!
```

why I cannot get the res when I use "swap!" ? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need this? There is no need for mutable state here, just use `partition-all`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I also want to try other ways (like using swap!) to solve this problem.

Comment: If you are using cider/nrepl+emacs the built in debugger shows this problem very well, just hit C-u C-c C-c on the function (eval with debugging) and then run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's blowing up in the second pass through the loop.

`swap` returns the *value* that was put into the atom, not the atom it's self. So the first pass is updating the atom, and then passing the value it just put into the atom to the second pass through the loop. in the second pass it's trying to use the value as the atom, and getting the exception above.

To "fix" this use a `do` to update the atom, then pass the atom to the next pass through the loop once it contains the correct value.

```
user> (defn collect [lst num]
        (loop [l lst res (atom ())]
          (if (<= (count l) num) @res
              (recur (drop num l) 
                     (do (swap! res conj (take num (drop num l))) 
                         res)))))
#'user/collect
user> (collect '(a b c d e) 2)
((e) (c d))
```

You can also in this case, just remove the atom completely and get exactly the same result (I fixed on ordering problem from your example by using a `[]` instead of `()` in the initial value of res):

```
user> (defn collect [lst num]
        (loop [l lst res []]
          (if (<= (count l) num) res
              (recur (drop num l) 
                     (conj res (take num (drop num l)))))))
#'user/collect
user> (collect '(a b c d e) 2)
[(c d) (e)]
```

and of course you can also use `partition-all` as glts mentions above.

Answer (score 1):

```
;; this would be a correct way to do it
(defn collect [coll n]
  (partition-all n coll))

;; this would be a clumsy way to do it
(defn collect
  "using a loop (there is not point to do that but at least you can see the logic working as in your example)"
  [coll n]
  (lazy-seq
   (loop [res []
          coll coll]
     (if (empty? coll)
       res
       (recur (conj res (take n coll)) (drop n coll))))))
```

Regarding your error, on the second loop, `res` is a list-like value, not an `atom` anymore. That would lead us to :

```
(defn collect [coll n]
  (lazy-seq (loop [res (atom [])
                   coll coll]
              (if (empty? coll)
                @res
                (recur (do (swap! res conj (take n coll))
                           ;; return the atom instead of the value'
                           res)
                       (drop n coll))))))
```

Note that in order to preserve the order in the solution, I use a vector (litteral `[]`) instead of a list (litteral `'()`). This is because of the behaviour of `conj` [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17910673/1327651).